# php foreach not iterating

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

`$email` is the name of a table in my database. When I execute the mysql query in phpmyadmin, I correctly get two `casenum`s, 1 and 3.

However, when I try to loop through the array, `echo $caseNum."<br>";` prints

```
1 
1
```

instead of

```
1
3
```

**The code:**

```
$_SESSION['caseNums'] = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT `casenum` FROM `$email`"));
$_SESSION['cases'] = array();

foreach($_SESSION['caseNums'] as $caseNum) {
echo $caseNum."<BR>";
}
```

Comment: **WARNING**: This looks terrifyingly insecure because those parameters are not [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php). You should **NEVER** put `$_POST` data directly into the query: it creates a gigantic [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used, it's being removed from PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices.

Comment: Those are session variables guy.  They come from the server.

Comment: .... and were supplied by the user, who might just have been [Little Johnny Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's to be expected. `mysql_fetch_array()` returns a **SINGLE** row of data from your query, with dual string+integer keys.

In other words, you're printing out the value retrieved from the first row of data only, and printing it twice because it was duplicated in the returned array.

You need:

```
$result = mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
   $_SESSION['caseNums'][] = $row[0];
}
```